# Is there a way to enforce a minimum WiFi quality level before switching from mobile networks?

Tags: wi-fi

My phone has access to various hotspot networks in the area I live in. When I walk down the street, now and again I pass by a hotspot and my phone will attempt to connect.

As often as not, the phone will connect, but for whatever reason, it will be a weak connection, and effectively my internet access stops. My phone abandons my cellular network connection in favour of the wifi, even though the wifi is bringing in little or no data.

Is there a way I can enforce a minimum standard of connectivity to a wifi network so that my phone won't leave my mobile connection in favour of hotspots that are useless?

Comment: For preventing mobile to WiFi switchover, when latter strength is low, see in developer options, *aggressive WiFi to mobile handover* should help (not tried by me)

Comment: @beeshyams,Thank you for responding. I've set the option as you suggested, so I will give it a day or so to see if it really does make a difference.

Comment: @beeshyams, so, I've tried the aggressive wifi handover option for the last few days, and unfortunately I can't say that it has made a noticeable improvement. I still find that my phone will favour near-useless wifi connections over mobile data. So, thank you for the suggestion, but it seems I'm still in search of a solution.

Comment: If automation is an option try [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid). This macro disables your WiFi when you are away from home network. Of course, you have to enable manually, when you want to connect to a hotspot. *Trigger:* disconnect from WiFi network ( your home NW) *Action:*  Disable WiFi *Constraints:* None. This is a basic approach and can be refined